# put uiscroll view without help of xib want to make programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview

I want to put scroll bar without help of `xib` and I am using this piece of code but when I add level or any but.

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    scrollView.contentSize   = CGSizeMake(1947, 1800);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    // [imageView release];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: this code is working fine..... what the issue?

Comment: but?..what?..forgot to post whole question?

Answer (score 0):

I am completely not understand your question. may this help you.

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,1024,668)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024,768);
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator =YES;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
    scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
    scrollView.bounces = YES;
    scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
    scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Comment: your question is not so clear. Explain it more so someone can help you to slove this problem.

Comment: I want to add scroll view to my view and add some label and button on scroll view and i want everything programatically but i am unable to attach the scroll view programatically